# Adding /healthz to NGINX Docker image

Tags: docker, nginx, google-kubernetes-engine, nginx-config

I am trying to deploy an `nginx` docker image. I need to create an endpoint to be used by my readiness probe, this should be a simple `/healthz` endpoint that returns a 200 / OK.

I have tried the below, however this causes the browser to download a file containing the response and not render it as doc.

```
server {
    listen       80;
    server_name  localhost;

    location /healthz {
        return 200 "OK\n";
    }

    location / {

        root   /usr/share/nginx/html;
        index  index.html index.htm;
        try_files $uri /index.html;                 
    }

    # redirect server error pages
    #
    error_page   500 502 503 504  /50x.html;
    location = /50x.html {
        root   /usr/share/nginx/html;
    }

}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The default content-type is `application/octet-stream`.

Try adding `add_header Content-Type text/plain;`

```
location / {
    add_header Content-Type text/plain;
    return 200 'OK';
}
```